# ioutil.ReadAll fails miserably

Tags: go, io, null, reader

I'm trying to get an io.Reader back from this weather it's a link or a path I'm given. For some context I'm using flags

```
func getString(link, path string) (io.Reader, error) {

    var dick io.ReadWriter

    if link != "" {
        resp, err := http.Get(link)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        io.Copy(dick, resp.Body)
    }

    if path != "" {
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        io.Copy(dick, file)
    }

    return dick, nil

}
```

and boom

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x46e949]
```

this bad boy comes along

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`io.ReadWriter` is an interface, what you need is an instance of `io.ReadWriter` to write into (via io.Copy) and return the `io.Reader` interface off of that.

One type that comes to mind is a `bytes.Buffer`.  Your code would look like this

```
func getString(link, path string) (io.Reader, error) {

    dick := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    if link != "" {
        resp, err := http.Get(link)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        io.Copy(dick, resp.Body)
    }

    if path != "" {
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        io.Copy(dick, file)
    }

    return dick, nil

}
```

You are also swallowing the error from `io.Copy` which isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

Simply declaring a variable (`dick`) as an interface type (`io.ReadWriter`) does not create a concrete type that will handle the interface method implementations.

`dick` still needs access to a type that actually implements the `Read` and `Write` methods. See [here](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) for more details about how interfaces work.

As for the error above, you can use a [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer). This type already satisfies the `io.ReadWriter` interface.

```
func getString(link, path string) (io.Reader, error) {
    var dick bytes.Buffer // bytes.Buffer is an io.ReadWriter.
    if link != "" {
        resp, err := http.Get(link)
        // ...
        io.Copy(dick, resp.Body)
    }
    // ...
    return dick, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a `Reader` back from the function, it's much simpler than the other answers make it out to be. The `io.Copy`, buffer, etc is completely unnecessary:

```
func getString(link, path string) (io.Reader, error) {
    if link != "" {
        resp, err := http.Get(link)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        return resp.Body, err // http.Response.Body implements io.Reader
    }

    if path != "" {
        return os.Open(path) // os.File implements io.Reader
    }

    return nil, errors.New("No path or link given")
}
```

You might want to return an `io.ReadCloser` so that the caller knows it needs to, and will be able to, close it once it finishes reading from it. Both `Body` and `File` implement `ReadCloser` so the only change needed would be the function's return signature.